# Assets compile failed with out of memory and not able to ssh into server now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, ssh, asset-pipeline

I'm using Amazon instance to to run my Ubuntu server, i depyoed new feature and did

> rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=staging

but i got error while pre-compiling

> **Allocation failed - process out of memory precompile**

I found out that my CUP usage was 100%. I exit that proecess. But now i'm not able to SSH in to my server. The instance on AWS is running state. 
it says **ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, It turned out I was running multiple process like sidekiq, rails console and my error logs in other terminal. So it drained a lot of RAM memory that time.This is why the server stopped responding.

I restated the Instance so i was able to log in to the SSH and then only ran precompaile and it worked. Still the memory usage was around 95% but other processes were close that time,so the precompailatoin ran successfully.

I'm using this server just as staging/testing server before  production so there is no point of increasing memory(As of now). SO the above solution worked for me. Hope this might come in hand for you guys.